# Minimal irrep of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,p) $

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Let $ p $ be a prime for which $ \PSL(2,p) $ is simple (so $ p \neq 2,3 $).

Is the minimal irrep of $ \PSL(2,p) $ defined over a quadratic extension? In particular I wish to ask:
for $ p $ congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $ is $ \PSL(2,p) $ always a subgroup of
$$
 \SO_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})) 
$$
and for $ p $ congruent to $ 3 $ mod $ 4 $ if $ \PSL(2,p) $ is always a subgroup of
$$
 \SU_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})) 
$$

For example, this is true for $ p=5 $ with the "icosahedral" $ A_5\cong \PSL(2,5) $ subgroup of $ \SO_3 $. Appropriate generators are given in the section "Coxeter group generators" of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry

Background:

The minimal degree $ d_{\min} $ of a nontrivial irrep of $ \PSL(2,p) $ is
$$
d_{\min}=\frac{p+1}{2}
$$
if $ p $ is congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $ and is
$$
d_{\min}=\frac{p-1}{2}
$$
if $ p $ is congruent to $ 3 $ mod $ 4 $.

The value of the characters for degree $ d_{\min} $ irreps are mostly $ 0,1,-1 $s also of course $ d_{\min} $ and finally either
$$
\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}
$$
if $ p $ is congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $ or
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{-p}}{2}
$$
if $ p $ is congruent to $ 3 $ mod $ 4 $. There are always exactly two irreps of degree $ d_{\min} $ and their characters are related exactly by  conjugation in the corresponding quadratic extension. All this information is in the first two nontrivial characters which can be found, for example, here

[http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jda/characters/psl2/](http://www2.math.umd.edu/%7Ejda/characters/psl2/)

Update: At this point I feel confident that, for $ p $ congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $, there is a $ PSL(2,p) $ subgroup of
$$
 \SO_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{R}) 
$$
and a $ PSL(2,p) $ subgroup of
$$
 \SL_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})) 
$$
I'm still trying to understand if there is a $ PSL(2,p) $ subgroup of
$$
\SO_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})) =  \SL_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})) \cap  \SO_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{R}) 
$$
Similarly, for $ p $ congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $, there is a $ PSL(2,p) $ subgroup of
$$
 \SU_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{R}) 
$$
and a $ PSL(2,p) $ subgroup of
$$
 \SL_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})) 
$$
I'm still trying to understand if there is a $ PSL(2,p) $ subgroup of
$$
\SU_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})) =  \SL_{d_{\min}}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})) \cap  \SU_{d_{\min}}
$$

Every representation is a determinant 1 since $ PSL(2,p) $ is simple ( for $ p \neq 2,3 $).

And we can always find a representation defined over the appropriate quadratic extension $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pm p}) $ since every character of $ PSL(2,p) $ has Schur index 1 (thanks to @BenjaminSteinberg for this fact that an irrep with Schur index 1 can always be realized over the field generated by its character values for the fact that $ PSL(2,p) $ always has Schur index 1 see part (I) of Theorem 6.1 of https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02762888.pdf).

For $ p $ congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $ we can always find an orthogonal representation since the Frobenius-Schur indicator is $ 1 $ (indeed every irrep of $ PSL(2,p) $ for $ p $ congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $ has FS indicator $ 1 $, this is related to the fact that for such $ p $ every element of $ PSL(2,p) $ is strongly real, meaning conjugate to its inverse by an involution, and thus the group as a whole is totally orthogonal, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.05343 for details).

Comment: I think that the best way to look at this is via Weil representations. I don't have time at the moment to pursue the details myself,  but the idea is as follows. Think of ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ as ${\rm Sp}(2,p)$ ( which it is. This gives an action of ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ as a group of automorphisms of $E$, an extra-special group of order $p^{3}$ and exponent $p$, wjere the action on $Z(E)$ is trivial. Then a monomial irreducible $p$-dimensional complex representation of $E$ extends (almost uniquely, ie, up to scalar multiples) to a unitary representation of the split extension $E{\rm SL}(2,p)$.

Comment: The restriction of this representation to ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ breaks up as a sum of two irreducible pieces ( which explains the dependence of the congruence of $p$ (mod $4$)),

Comment: One irreducible constituent is on the $-1$-eigenspace of the unique involution $t$ of ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ . It has dimension $\frac{p \pm 1}{2}$ ( the one one which is even, as ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ is prefect). The other irreducible constituent has dimension $\frac{p \mp 1}{2}$, and is afforded by the $1$-eigenspace of $t$. The field of realizability of these irreducible pieces is fairly easy to computes.

Comment: Googling Schur index PSL(2,p) might turn something up.  If it is 1 then you can define the representation over any field containing the character values

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg part(I) of Theorem 6.1 of "The computations of some Schur Indices" by Walter Feit says that every irreducible character of $ PSL(2,q) $ for every prime power $ q $ has Schur Index 1. One thing I'm a bit concerned about is that for example that implies the 2d irrep of $ PSL(2,2)\cong S_3 $ has Schur index $ 1 $. However I believe that there is no $ S_3 $ subgroup of $ O_3(\mathbb{Q}) $. As you point out this 2d irrep can be defined over $ \mathbb{Q} $, as a subgroup of $ GL_2(\mathbb{Q}) $ but it seems there is no way to make the irrep simultaneously rational and orthogonal.

Comment: That's a good question.  I guess that when you average out the inner product to get an invariant inner product, you run the risk of adding some squareroots.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Any chance you could explain why the Weil representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ can be defined over the quadratic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ (if I am right that it can)? The standard formulas for it involve the finite Fourier transform, and hence have matrix entries which are $p$-th roots of unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}\def\Sp{\text{Sp}}\def\SL{\text{SL}}\def\GL{\text{GL}}$Okay, time to do both cases using the Weil representation. This is going to rely on some Key Facts which I can check from my [explicit matrices for the Weil representation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432407) and which I do not know how to prove abstractly.

**Notation:** Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity. Let $L = \QQ(\zeta)$. Let $p^{\ast} = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} p$ and let $K = \QQ(\sqrt{p^{\ast}})$, this is the unique quadratic subfield of $L$. Let $\chi(a)$ be the quadratic residue symbol $\left( \tfrac{a}{p} \right)$.
For $a \in \FF_p^{\times}$, let $\sigma_a$ be the element of $\text{Gal}(L/\QQ)$ with $\sigma_a(\zeta) = \zeta^a$.

For $a \in \FF_p^{\times}$, let $t(a)$ be the matrix $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} a  & 0 \\ 0 & a^{-1}  \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ in $\SL_{2}(\FF_p)$. I'll write $\gamma : \SL_{2}(\FF_p) \to \SL_{p}(\mathbb{C})$ for the Weil representation. (This argument will also extend to the Weil representation of $\Sp_{2k}(\FF_p)$ for $k>1$.)

Here are the key facts:

**Key Facts** We can choose the map $\gamma$ such that all of the following are simultaneously true:

(1) All the matrices $\gamma(g)$ are in $\SL_{p}(L)$.

(2) For $a \in \FF_p^{\times}$, we have $\sigma_{a^2}(\gamma(g)) = \gamma(t(a)^{-1} g t(a))$.

(3) The matrices $t(\gamma(a))$ are $\pm 1$ times the permutation matrices with permute  $\FF_p$ by multiplication by $a$. Specifically, the sign is $\chi(a)$.

**Writing down the minimal representation:**

The involution $t(-1)$ is central in $\SL_2(\FF_p)$. Using Key Fact (3) above, it acts on the Weil representation with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, having multiplicities $\tfrac{p + \chi(-1)}{2}$ and $\tfrac{p-\chi(-1)}{2}$ respectively; the $1$-eigenspace is the representation which factors through $\text{PSL}_2(\FF_p)$. I'll write $\gamma_+(g)$ for the action of $g \in \SL_2(\FF_p)$ on this $1$-eigenspace. We will need to understand this more explicitly:

When $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, the matrix $\gamma(t(-1))$ is the permutation matrix $b \mapsto -b$ on $\FF_p$. So we can think of the $1$-eigenspace as even functions on $\FF_p$, or in other words as functions on $\FF_p/\{ \pm 1 \}$. We can think of $\gamma_+(t(a))$ as the permutation $a$ acting on $\FF_p/\{\pm 1\}$, times $\chi(a)$.

When $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, the matrix $\gamma(t(-1))$ is $-1$ times the permutation matrix $b \mapsto -b$ on $\FF_p$. So we can think of the $1$-eigenspace as odd functions on $\FF_p$. Write $S$ for the group of quadratic residues in $\FF_p^{\times}$. For any $a \in \FF_p^{\times}$, exactly one of $a$ and $-a$ is in $S$, so an odd function is determined by its value on $S$, so we can think of the $1$-eigenspace as functions on $S$. We can think of $\gamma_+(t(a))$ as the permutation $\chi(a) a$ acting on $S$.

**Conjugating into $\SL(K)$**

Let $\delta$ be a matrix in $\GL(L)$. We'd like to have $\delta \gamma_+(g) \delta^{-1} \in \SL(K)$ for all $g$ in $\SL_2(\FF_p)$. Now, $K$ is the fixed field of the subgroup $\{ \sigma_{a^2}: a \in \FF_p \}$, so we want to have
$$\sigma_{a^2}(\delta \gamma_+(g) \delta^{-1}) = \delta \gamma_+(g) \delta^{-1}.$$
We can rewrite the LHS as
$$\sigma_{a^2}(\delta) \sigma_{a^2}(\gamma_+(g)) \sigma_{a^2}(\delta)^{-1} =
\sigma_{a^2}(\delta) \gamma_+(t(a))^{-1} \gamma_+(g) \gamma_+(t(a)) \sigma_{a^2}(\delta)^{-1}.$$
So we want
$$\sigma_{a^2}(\delta) \gamma_+(t(a))^{-1} \gamma_+(g) \gamma_+(t(a)) \sigma_{a^2}(\delta)^{-1} = \delta \gamma_+(g) \delta^{-1}$$
or, in other words,
we want
$$\delta^{-1} \sigma_{a^2}(\delta) \gamma_+(t(a))^{-1}$$
to commute with all $\gamma_+(g)$.
Since the representation $\gamma_+$ is irreducible, by Schur's lemma, this will happen if and only if
$$\sigma_{a^2}(\delta) = c_a \delta \gamma_+(t(a)) \qquad (\ast)$$
for all $a \in \FF_p^{\times}$, for some scalar $c_a \in L^{\times}$.
Our goal, therefore, is to write down an invertible matrix $\delta$ with entries in $L$, satisfying $(\ast)$.

**Finding $\delta$**

In the case that $p = 3 \bmod 4$, we think of the rows and columns of $\delta$ as indexed by $S$. We define the matrix $\delta$ by $\delta_{yx} = \zeta^{y^2 x^2}$. Since $x \mapsto x^2$ is a permutation of $S$, this is a Vandermonde matrix and hence invertible. (Really, $y^2$ could be replaced by any bijection $S \to S$, but the $x^2$ term is important, and I thought it was most elegant to use the same formula for both.)

For $a \in S$, we have $\sigma_{a^2}(\zeta^{y^2 x^2}) = \zeta^{a^2 (y^2x^2)} = \zeta^{y^2 (ax)^2}$. The latter is the $(y,x)$ entry in $\delta \gamma_+(t(a))$. This checks $(\ast)$ for $a \in S$; if $-a \in S$ instead, then note that $\sigma_{a^2} = \sigma_{(-a)^2}$ and $\gamma_+(t(a)) = \gamma_+(t(-a))$. So we have checked $(\ast)$ with $c_a = 1$.

Now, let's do the $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ case. In this case, we think of the rows and columns of $\delta$ as indexed by $\FF_p/ \{ \pm 1 \}$. Once again, we define $\delta$ by $\delta_{yx} = \zeta^{y^2 x^2}$. Once again, this is a Vandermonde matrix, and thus invertible. If $\gamma_+(t(a))$ acted by the permutation of multiplication by $a$ on $\FF_p/ \{ \pm 1 \}$, we would once again verify $(\ast)$ with $c_a = 1$. Since, in fact, $\gamma_+(t_(a))$ is $\chi(a)$ times this permutation matrix, we still win, but with $c_a = \chi(a)$.

Answer (score 5):

$\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}$I can do the $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ case. It is always defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$.

In this case, we can describe the minimal representation as follows: Let $A$ be a two dimensional $\FF_p$-vector space. For $c \in \FF_p$, set $\chi(c) := \left( \tfrac{c}{p} \right)$. Let $U$ be the vector space of all functions $u:A \to \mathbb{Q}$ satisfying
$$u(c \vec{a}) = \chi(c) u(\vec{a}) \ \text{for all}\ c \in \FF_p,\ \vec{a} \in A.$$
The vector space $U$ has dimension $p+1$ since, if we choose one vector on each line in $A$, then the value of $u$ on those vectors determines $u$ everywhere else. Note that $\text{PGL}_2(\FF_p)$ acts on $U$: It is obvious that $\text{GL}_2(\FF_p)$ does, and the condition $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ implies that $\chi(-1) = 1$, so the action descends to $\text{PGL}_2(\FF_p)$.

Now, fix a nonzero skew symmetric form $\langle \ , \ \rangle : A \times A \to \FF_p$. Define a linear map $F : U \to U$ as
$$F(u)(\vec{a}) = \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\vec{b} \in A} \chi{\big(} \langle \vec{a}, \vec{b} \rangle {\big)} u(\vec{b}).$$
The $\tfrac{1}{p-1}$ factor is for convenience; note that the $p-1$ proportional vectors on any line in $A$ all make the same contribution. Note that this formula is given by a matrix with entries in $\QQ$. (In fact, the matrix entries are in $\ZZ$, because we can just choose one representative vector on each line.)

Note that the operator $F$ is $\text{PSL}_2(\FF_p)$ equivariant since the form $\langle \ , \rangle$ is $\text{SL}_2(\FF_p)$ invariant.

**Lemma** $F^2 = p \text{Id}$.

**Proof:**
Choose coordinates on $A$ such that $\langle \ , \ \rangle$ is the standard form, and set $\vec{b}_{\infty} := \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1\\0 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ and $b_j := \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} j\\1 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ for $0 \leq j \leq p-1$. Then
$$F(u)(\vec{a}) =  \sum_{j} \chi{\big(} \langle \vec{a}, \vec{b}_j \rangle {\big)} u(\vec{b}_j).$$
and
$$F^2(u)(\vec{a}) = \sum_{j,k} \chi{\big(} \langle \vec{a}, \vec{b}_j \rangle {\big)} \chi{\big(} \langle \vec{b}_j, \vec{b}_k \rangle {\big)}  u(\vec{b}_k).$$

It is enough to verify the claim for a spanning set of $U$. Such a spanning set is given by the functions which are supported on the various lines of $A$. By symmetry, it is enough to consider one such function: Let $u(\vec{a}) = \chi(c)$ if $\vec{a} = c \vec{b}_{\infty}$, and $0$ otherwise. Then
$$F(u)(\vec{b}_i) = \begin{cases} 1 & 0 \leq i \leq p-1 \\ 0 & i= \infty \\ \end{cases}.$$
We have
$$F^2(u)(\vec{b}_i) = \begin{cases} \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} \chi(j-i) \\  \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} 1  \end{cases} = \begin{cases} 0 & 0 \leq i \leq p-1 \\ p & i = \infty \end{cases}.$$
In other words, $F^2 = p \text{Id}$ as desired. $\square$

Now, extend scalars to $\QQ(\sqrt{p})$. Then $U$ splits into $\pm \sqrt{p}$ eigenspaces for $F$ and, since $F$ has matrix entries in $\QQ$, its eigenspaces have coordinates in $\QQ(\sqrt{p})$. Since $F$ is $\text{PSL}_2(\FF_p)$-equivariant, the action of $\text{PSL}_2(\FF_p)$ maps each eigenspace to itself. These eigenspaces are the minimal representations.

---

I clearly have constructed a nontrivial $\tfrac{p+1}{2}$-dimensional representation of $\text{PSL}_2(\FF_p)$, so it must be the minimal representation. How did I come up with this?

Let $B$ be the subgroup $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} c & d \\ 0 & c^{-1} \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ of $G:=\text{PSL}_2(\FF_p)$. Then we have a character $\psi : B \to \{ \pm 1 \}$ defined by $\psi\left( \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} c & d \\ 0 & c^{-1} \end{smallmatrix} \right] \right) = \chi(c)$. The vector space $U$ is just the induction of $\psi$ from $B$ to $G$, described in the standard way as functions on cosets.

I knew from the general theory that $U = U_+ \oplus U_-$ where $U_+$ and $U_-$ are the two minimal representations, so we should have $\dim \text{Hom}_G(U, U) = 2$. I knew that, if I could find a non-scalar element $F$ of $\text{Hom}_G(U, U)$, then I could recover $U_+$ and $U_-$ as its eigenspaces. The advantage of $\text{Hom}_G(U, U)$ is that I can compute it using matrices with entries in $\QQ$.

The principled way to proceed would then be to compute $\text{Hom}_G(U, U)$ by using Frobenius reciprocity; it should be $\text{Hom}_B(\psi,\ \text{Res}_B^G \text{Ind}_B^G \psi)$. I started trying to do this, but I got confused, so I decided to try guessing instead.

The formula $F^2 = p \text{Id}$ and the presence of $\text{SL}_2$ reminded me of the finite Fourier transform $\Phi(u)(\vec{a})  = \sum_{\vec{b}} \eta(\langle \vec{a}, \vec{b} \rangle) u(\vec{b})$, where $\eta : \FF_p \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is an additive character.  But this is given by a matrix with entries in $\QQ(\zeta_p)$, and I wanted  a matrix with entries in $\QQ$. After some more thought, I realized I could replace the additive character $\eta$ by the multiplicative character which was already present in the definition of $U$, and this worked.

Comment: I'll think a bit more about what the invariant quadratic form on $U$ (and hence on the $F$-eigenspaces)  looks like when I get a chance.

Comment: Do you think it would make the question more manageable if I restricted it to the case of $ p $ congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $ and spun off the congruent to $ 3 $ mod $ 4 $ case into a different question?

Comment: I suppose so, I think it is also okay as it is. The way I have been thinking about it is in terms of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, not $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$. In that case, there are two $\tfrac{p+1}{2}$-dimensional representations, which this answer shows are defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p^{\ast}})$, and there are two $\tfrac{p-1}{2}$-dimensional representations, which I don't know how to handle. Here $p^{\ast} = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} p$.

Comment: Aha! The $\tfrac{p-1}{2}$ dimensional representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ are NOT defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p^*})$ in the $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ case. Or at least, not when $p=5$. The group $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ is the binary icosahedral group, and its two dimensional representations are quaternionic -- one of them is, in fact, the standard way to embed the binary icosahedral group into the unit quaternions. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is real, this means that the two dimensional representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ are not defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: (This doesn't create a problem for the OP, since the $\tfrac{p-1}{2}$-dimensional representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ don't factor through $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.)

Comment: Now that I know that I should stop trying to prove something false, I think I can handle the $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ case.