# Minimal irrep of $\mathrm{SL}(2,2^r) $

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$
This is in some ways a follow up post to [Minimal irrep of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,p) $](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432148/minimal-irrep-of-mathrmpsl2-p).

The minimal dimension $ d_{\min} $ of a nontrivial irrep of $ \SL(2,2^r) $ is
$$
d_{\min}=q-1=2^r-1.
$$

What is the minimal degree extension of $ \mathbb{Q} $ over which a $ d_{\min} $ dimensional irrep of $ \SL(2,2^r) $ is defined?

For example, for $ q=2^r=4 $ the "icosahedral" $ A_5\cong \SL(2,4) $ subgroup of $ \SO_3 $ is defined over a quadratic field extension $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) $. Appropriate generators are given in the section "Coxeter group generators" of [the Wikipedia entry on icosahedral symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry).

But for $ q=8 $ the situation is already very different. There are many embeddings into $ \SO_7(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9+ \overline{\zeta_9})) $ as might be expected but there is also a single embedding into $ \SO_7(\mathbb{Q}) $, which I find surprising.

This reoccurs for $ q=32 $ where again there are many embeddings into $ \SO_{31}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{33}+ \overline{\zeta_{33}})) $ but a single irrep embedding into $ \SO_{31}(\mathbb{Q}) $.

Background:

The value of the characters for degree $ d_{\min} $ irreps include some integers but mostly the character values are algebraic numbers from the real subfield $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{q+1}+\overline{\zeta_{q+1}}) $ of $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{q+1}) $.

All this information can be found, for example, at [Adams - Character Table of $\SL(2, q)$](http://www2.math.umd.edu/%7Ejda/characters/sl2).

Every representation is determinant 1 since $ \SL(2,2^r)=\PSL(n,2^r) $ is simple (except $ \SL(2,2) \cong S_3 $).

And we can always find a representation defined over the extension $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{q+1}+\overline{\zeta_{q+1}}) $ since every character of $ \SL(2,2^r) $ has Schur index 1 (thanks to [@BenjaminSteinberg](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432148/minimal-irrep-of-mathrmpsl2-p#comment1112341_432148) for this fact that an irrep with Schur index 1 can always be realized over the field generated by its character values, for the fact that $ \PSL(2,q) $ always has Schur index 1 see part (I) of Theorem 6.1 of [Feit - The computations of some Schur indices](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02762888)).

For $ q=2^r $ we can always find an orthogonal representation since the Frobenius–Schur indicator is $ 1 $ (indeed every irrep of $ \SL(2,2^r) $ has FS indicator $ 1 $, this is related to the fact that every element of $ \SL(2,2^r) $ is strongly real, meaning conjugate to its inverse by an involution, and thus the group as a whole is totally orthogonal, see [Vinroot - Totally orthogonal finite simple groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.05343) for details).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $q=2^n$ then $q+1$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if $n$ is odd. This is precisely when, on the cyclic subgroup of order $q+1$ there is a non-trivial one dimensional character $\chi$ for which $\chi + \bar\chi$ is rational ($\chi$ has order three).

So if $n$ is odd, $\operatorname{SL}(2,q)$ has a rational character of degree $q-1$. Otherwise, you have to look for a character $\chi$ of a cyclic group of order $q+1$ for which the field of $\chi + \bar\chi$ has as small a degree as possible.

The upshot is that for a character of degree $q-1$, if $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $q+1$ then the degree of the smallest field extension is $(p-1)/2$.

For example for $q=64$ we have $p=5$ and $(p-1)/2=2$, so there is a degree $63$ character defined over a quadratic number field (the icosahedral one).